# Object isn't updating in tableview with new Realm data

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, realm

Whenever I click on a row in my tableview and change the text in the fields to something else, it always crashes and doesn't actually update the data. I'm saving all my data in a "Realm" database, which im fairly new at using.

I'm doing the updating in the "unwindToNoteList" function. Can someone help me know why it's adding a new row and crashing instead of updating the current row?

```
import UIKit
import Realm

class NoteTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Properties

    var notes = Note.allObjects()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Get Realm Database location
        println(RLMRealm.defaultRealm().path)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return Int(notes.count)
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "NoteTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NoteTableViewCell

        let object = notes[UInt(indexPath.row)] as! Note

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.titleLabel.text = object.title
        cell.bodyLabel.text = object.body

        return cell
    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {

            // Delete from database
            let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
            realm.beginWriteTransaction()
            realm.deleteObject(notes[UInt(indexPath.row)] as! RLMObject)
            realm.commitWriteTransaction()

            // Delete row from table view
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" { // Clicked on a cell
            let noteDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NoteViewController
            // Get the cell that generated this segue.
            if let selectedNoteCell = sender as? NoteTableViewCell {
                let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedNoteCell)!

                let selectedNote = notes[UInt(indexPath.row)] as! Note
                noteDetailViewController.note = selectedNote

            }
        }
        else if segue.identifier == "AddItem" { // Clicked add button
            println("Adding new note")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToNoteList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
               if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() { // User clicked on a row

            // Update an existing note.
            let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
            realm.beginWriteTransaction()

            Note.createOrUpdateInRealm(realm, withValue: ["title": note.title, "body": note.body, "id": note.id])
            realm.commitWriteTransaction()

            println("Yes")

            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        }
        else {
            // Add a new note.
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: Int(notes.count), inSection: 0)

            // Persist in database
            let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
            realm.beginWriteTransaction()
            Note.createInRealm(realm, withValue: ["title": note.title, "body": note.body, "id": uuid])
            realm.commitWriteTransaction()

            println("no")

            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
        }
        }
    }

}
```

**Finally solved this, by not updating the object while in the tableview but while in the view controller that holds the text fields**

Here's my NoteViewController

```
import UIKit
import Realm

class NoteViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var bodyTextField: UITextField!

    /*
    This value is either passed by `NoteTableViewController` in `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)`
    or constructed as part of adding a new note.
    */
    var note = Note?()

    // MARK: Navigation

    @IBAction func cancel(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.
        let isPresentingInAddNoteMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController
        if isPresentingInAddNoteMode {
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }

    // This method lets you configure a view controller before it's presented.
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if saveButton === sender {
            let title = titleTextField.text ?? ""
            let body = bodyTextField.text ?? ""

            /* The operator ?? unwraps the optional string in titleTextField.text since it may or may not have text in the field, and returns the value if it's a valid string. If nil though, it returns and empty string ("") instead
            */

            // Update the database
            let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
            realm.beginWriteTransaction()

            note?.title = titleTextField.text
            note?.body = bodyTextField.text

            realm.commitWriteTransaction()

            // Set the note to be passed to NoteTableViewController after the unwind segue.
            // AKA pass "note" to NoteTableViewController with whatever the text fields have in them
            note = Note(title: title, body: body)
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
        titleTextField.delegate = self

        // Set up views if editing an existing Note.
        if let note = note {
            navigationItem.title = note.title
            titleTextField.text = note.title
            bodyTextField.text = note.body
        }

        // Enable the Save button only if the text field has a valid Note name.
        checkValidNoteName()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        // Disable the Save button while editing.
        saveButton.enabled = false
    }

    func checkValidNoteName() {
        // Disable the Save button if the text field is empty.
        let text = titleTextField.text ?? ""
        saveButton.enabled = !text.isEmpty
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        checkValidNoteName()
        navigationItem.title = textField.text
    }


}
```

And here's the original, NoteTableViewController. Updated a bit as well.

```
import UIKit
import Realm

class NoteTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  // MARK: Properties

    var notes = Note.allObjects()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Get Realm Database location
        println(RLMRealm.defaultRealm().path)

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return Int(notes.count)
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "NoteTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NoteTableViewCell

        let object = notes[UInt(indexPath.row)] as! Note

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.titleLabel.text = object.title
        cell.bodyLabel.text = object.body

        return cell
    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {

            // Delete from database
            let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
            realm.beginWriteTransaction()
            realm.deleteObject(notes[UInt(indexPath.row)] as! RLMObject)
            realm.commitWriteTransaction()

            // Delete row from table view
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" { // Clicked on a cell
            let noteDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NoteViewController
            // Get the cell that generated this segue.
            if let selectedNoteCell = sender as? NoteTableViewCell {
                let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedNoteCell)!

                let selectedNote = notes[UInt(indexPath.row)] as! Note
                noteDetailViewController.note = selectedNote

            }
        }
        else if segue.identifier == "AddItem" { // Clicked add button
            println("Adding new note")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToNoteList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? NoteViewController, note = sourceViewController.note {

            let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString // Needed for primary key. see below

            var unwindedNote = Note()

            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() { // User clicked on a row

                // Updating of the note is done in NoteViewController

                tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
            }
            else {
                // Add a new note.
                let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: Int(notes.count), inSection: 0)

                // Persist in database
                let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
                realm.beginWriteTransaction()

                unwindedNote.title = note.title
                unwindedNote.body = note.body
                unwindedNote.id = uuid // This is done for the primary key that Realm needs, unique for each object created.

                realm.addObjects([unwindedNote])
                realm.commitWriteTransaction()

                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and question. You can post the answer on its own, and even accept it. That is the proper indication  for others with a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you provided there, I was going to suggest that putting your Realm writing logic in the view controller segue-controlled methods might be a little too late.

I would normally recommend that you should place any logic involving Realm writes in a method that is explicitly called from a user interacting with it. For example, in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method when they tap on a table cell, and then once the write has completed, perform the segue (or segue unwinding) then.

In any case, good to hear you solved it!